# OK to wire shift register latch and clock together?

Tags: microcontroller, clock, shift-register, latch

The circuit diagram for the LED driver in this [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc59281.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1612065178529) shows the shift register latch and clock being wired together. Will this work? I would assume so since TI has it in their datasheet. However, the description for the SCLK pin says that "A rising edge on SCLK is allowed 100ns after a rising edge of LAT". If that's the case how is it okay to wire the latch and clock pins together?

Comment: You can wire the Serial clock and latch together. that timing of 100ns is the time it takes longer for the cmos switches in the shift storage array to update than it takes for the switch in the latch to update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The circuit diagram for the LED driver in this datasheet shows the shift register latch and clock being wired together.

It looks that way at first. But look at the /3 on the connection between IC1 and ICn. That means it is a 3 wire bus, not a single wire.

[image]

> Will this work?

No, because:

> A rising edge on SCLK is allowed 100ns after a rising edge of LAT

Comment: Ah, I was unaware that /3 was the notation for a 3 wire bus. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

You can wire the serial clock and latch together. That timing of 100 ns is the time it takes longer for the CMOS switches in the shift storage array to update than it takes for the switch in the latch to update.

This means that if you connect them together, then the latch will update 100 ns before the serial storage shifting array, so those bits you just shifted in won't be there yet; they are still stored but will only show up on the next clock.

So it works, but your outputs (except for Qh') will lag one clock behind (Qh' is connected directly to the memory array and not to the output array).

The Qh can be used as the Qh' in normal use, only when binding the serial clock and latch clock together this Qh' really becomes important other than not having this small extra load. Based on that you can already see that it will work when you tie them together, otherwise they wouldn't add a extra pin to make sure you can daisy chain them the exact same way, no matter if you use the serial clock and latch clock as one or separate pins.